# Using Start/End Modifier search with wordforms isue

Tags: sphinx

If I search on a table with a Name field using `"^Word$"` it will find it.

If I have a Wordform in a `Word1 Word2 > Word3` construction e.g.

```
United States of America > USA
```

the same query will work. However if I do the same wordform in reverse e.g. `Word3 > Word1 Word2`:

```
USA > United States of America
```

Then is is not found using the same start/end modifier. However my habit is to do `Word1 > Word2 Word3` so that Word 2 and Word 3 can still be found in a search which won't work the other way.

Is there a way to set up the Start/End modifier search so that it still finds `W1 > W2 W3`?

Comment: What version do you have? Are you using both definitions in wordforms (it should be only one of them)?

Comment: @aditirex 2.2.11-id64-release and if by "only one of them" you mean just `Word1 > Word2` and not `Word2 > Word1` then yes.

Comment: Do a show profile;query;show plan  (you should get 'united' and 'america'  with field_start/end) and also a call keywords('usa','indexname'). Could be an issue in 2.2.11 or some other setting that interferes.

Comment: @aditirex That/those commands don't give me much info but `Show Meta` gives me some (e.g. the three keywords).  Honestly this turns out to be an W > W1 W2 in `Wordforms` as if I try to do any query with `W NEAR/# anyword` I get an error such as `[Err] 1064 - index idx_test syntax error, unexpected '/' near '/2 USA`. I'm going to have to move my many many wordforms to my very complex config using regexp and that is going to be a nightmare to make sure I don't break anything but it seems to be the only choice right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only suggestion I have is to use `regexp_filter` to do the expansion, rather than wordforms.

```
regexp_filter = \bUSA\b => United States of America
```

or similar. benefit have more control over capitaization (eg only do uppercase USA)

This means, the expansion happens much earlier in the tokeniation process, meaning it has less effect on extended query syntax.

In theory a query

```
"^Word$"
```

should then be turned into

```
"^United States of America$"
```

which still works :)

I think wordforms dont work, because `America$` will have been put into the index as a keyword. But the query looking for both ^ and $ on the one word.

Comment: Yes I'm going to test moving some of the `W > W1 W2` to Regexp (which I also use extensively as well). I use WF when the map i simple. However now I'm discovering all such patterns fail with `NEAR/#` when I explicitly search on the `W` word with the following error `[Err] 1064 - index idx_test syntax error, unexpected '/' near '/2 USA`

Comment: Tested moving to regexp and works without issue BUT not idea on the ultimate effect on the index. I have a massively complex index which uses both wordforms and regexp_filter and have come to rely on the results. But clearly wordforrms not giving me the flexibility I need. I guess I'll slowly migrated some WF over and test to see what breaks but... man. Off the top of your head any thoughts on how a WF moved to regexp_ instead could break anything?